# Not able to add thymeleaf springsecurity or layout dialect to my app

Tags: spring, maven, security, thymeleaf

Hi guys i am stuggling for a while I am learning thymeleaf security in spring boot app and by no chance, I am not able to add springsecurity or layout dialect to my app

Using java 14 sdk

there is screenshot from intellij

[image]

pom file without dependencies that does not work

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security Config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

thx a lot

Comment: There is (as you have found) no such JAR as `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.0.4.RELEASE`. There is [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/3.0.4.RELEASE) for Spring Security 4 - and also see the official Thymeleaf list of downloads [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/download.html). Any good, recent Spring Boot tutorial should provide a valid set of dependencies. Maybe [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf) helps, as a starting point, which you can then extend?

Answer (score 0):

so i found out after several minutes that rebuild does not help u just have to write dependency even intellij does not recognize it and then small icon will appear ;) press m icon and u r good to go ;)

[image]